# Issues with filtering lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got an array reading from a file using numpy.genfromtxt. From that I calculated a list called renditen by doing

```
renditen = array_column1 - array_column2
```

renditen.dtype gives float64 and renditen looks like this:
[ -1.15  -3.    -5.95 ...,  13.8   15.     6.5 ]
My question is reagarding the following code line:

```
ew_trefferquote = len(renditen[renditen>0]) / len(renditen)
```

By that I want to get the percentage of positive list entries.
However, this line is only properly executed when I mark the line within Spyder editor and 
run the selected code. When I run the whole script within Spyder, ew_trefferquote is zero, although it shouldn't be. Is there anything wrong with that code line or could it be a Spyder issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening is that you're dividing an integer by another integer:

```
>>> renditen = np.array([-2,-1,0,10,20])
>>> renditen[renditen > 0]
array([10, 20])
>>> len(renditen[renditen > 0]) / len(renditen)
0
```

You can avoid this by making sure you're dividing a float:

```
>>> 1.0*len(renditen[renditen > 0]) / len(renditen)
0.4
>>> float(len(renditen[renditen > 0])) / len(renditen)
0.4
```

or alternatively you can `from __future__ import division` at the start of your program:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 2/3
0.6666666666666666
```

I can't explain why it would use float division when selected, but then I don't know anything about Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

I think the line should be:

```
ew_trefferquote = len([x for x in renditen if x > 0]) / len(renditen)
```

The way you currently have it you are trying to index into renditen using `renditen > 0`

Comment: Since `renditen` is a numpy array, I think the OP can index it that way.  `renditen > 0` will return a boolean array looking something like `array([False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)`.

Comment: That is the standard numpy masking syntax

Comment: Indeed, multiplying len(...) with 1.0 solved the problem. Although I thought Python converts number types by itself.